# Proof of properties of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let (X,d) a metric space, if  $A \subseteq X$ is not empty, show that:

i) $A$ is open if and only if $Fr(A) = \overline{A} / A$

ii) $A$ is closed if and only if $Fr(A) = A / int(A)$

iii) $X = int (A) \cup Fr(A) \cup int (X/A)$

I previously proved that $\overline{A} = Fr(A) \cup int(A) ...(\alpha)$

We have $A=int(A)$ because A is open, so for i), we have $Fr(a)= \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}$,  then I sustituted $Fr(A)$ in $(\alpha)$ and I got $\overline{A} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c} \cup A$

$\Rightarrow  \overline{A} / A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c} \cup A / A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}/ \emptyset= \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}= Fr(A)$

Is the above correct? How can I prove the other implication? Could you give me a hint for the other two items?

Comment: What does $Fr(A)$ mean?

Comment: @rubikscube09 Presumably the boundary ("frontera" in Spanish).

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: And it is also sometimes called the *frontier* in English and denoted by $\operatorname{Fr}(A)$ (e.g., in Willard’s *General Topology*).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Good to know, thank you

Comment: To prove item (ii) remember that in any metric space you have  $\text{int}(A) \cup \partial(A) = \overline{A}$ (disjoint union).

Comment: For proving the other $(i)$ implication you have $\overline{A}\cap A^c=\overline{A}\setminus A=\overline{A}\cap\overline{A^c}$. If you could somehow prove that $\overline{A^c}=A^c$, then $A$ would be open. The last one is consecuence of what you already know, $\overline{A}=\operatorname{Fr}(A)\cup \operatorname{Int}(A)$.

Comment: Your calculation in your attempt to prove (i) is incorrect. Your substitution actually gives you $$\overline{A}=\left(\overline{A}\cap\overline{A^c}\right)\cup A\,,$$ (note parentheses) and then $$\begin{align*}\overline{A}\setminus A&=\left(\left(\overline{A}\cap\overline{A^c}\right)\cup A\right)\setminus A\\&=\left(\left(\overline{A}\cap\overline{A^c}\right)\setminus A\right)\cup(A\setminus A)\\&=\left(\left(\overline{A}\cap\overline{A^c}\right)\setminus A\right)\cup\varnothing\\&=\left(\overline{A}\cap\overline{A^c}\right)\setminus A\\&=\operatorname{Fr}(A)\setminus A\,.
\end{align*}$$